# Making read-char input robust?

Tags: minibuffer, events

I need to read a char at a time to interactively build a filter string while I show the results in a regular buffer. And what I've written works, except when a cursor key is pressed  - then bang, I get a *"non-character input event message"* and my code exits.

Here's an example. If I run the following command, and hit one of the arrow keys, I get an error.

```
(defun foobar ()
  (interactive)
  (setq r (read-char)))
```

I've tried `read-char`, `read-event` and `read-char-exclusive` with and without `ignore-errors`. I've tried `read-char-choice` and logic that looks for the vector result a cursor key would give. Nothing works (although I can handle return and backspace perfectly.)

What do I need to do? I don't need the cursor keys to do anything; I just need to make it safe to press them.

Comment: Can you add a little code snippet that shows this problem?

Comment: You get the event with something as simple as this if you call it from the mininbuffer and then use a cursor key (sorry, I've backticked code but it still doesn't seem to format properly):
`(defun foobar()
    (interactive)
    (setq r (read-char)))`

Comment: Oh - and this also happens if it I use --load to start emacs with an init file consisting of nothing but that function. So we can eliminate interaction with any extensions. ... Excpet that read-char-exclusive now does work, which it didn't in my full init. Hmm.

Comment: ..And my emacs has just had a nervous breakdown: it goes crazy trying to start. I suspect that read-char-exclusive will work perfectly once I've debugged this other problem - I should have tested sooner with -q --load and a simplified .emacs!

Comment: 1. Show your code (more of it). 2. Say *why you are trying to use `read-char` from the minibuffer*. Normally, you do not need the minibuffer if you are using `read-char`, so please help us understand why you use that combination (e.g. what you are really trying to do). The minibuffer is a *buffer*. In the general case it allows multiple-char input and editing. `read-char` pays no attention to what buffer is current, and it reads only one event.

Comment: @ump Comments can't be multi line formatted. Instead edit your question to add the code snippet.

Comment: The question and proposed answer are unclear and misleading, and should be closed. Salvaging them would mean posing a different question altogether, and it sounds like that is anyway unneeded. The OP apparently learned something, but this Q & A doesn't help anyone learn; it just offers confusion.

Answer (score 3):

Ok: the answer really is just to use `read-char-exclusive` instead of `read-char`. It works perfectly.
I wasn't working for me because of some problem in my configurations.

Comment: No, that does not answer the question that you asked, which was about using the minibuffer. And the answer itself is unclear. And this is not the place to add helpful hints about Emacs (e.g., `-q`) that are irrelevant to the question. The question is unclear and should be closed.

Comment: @Drew No Drew. His question was how to read a character without causing a specific error message. The minibuffer is irrelevant. He talks about the minibuffer for lack of understanding.

Comment: @Drew and yes, the question was hard to understand (use the close button if you think it should be closed), but the answer is not wrong.

Comment: @Malabarba: The *question as posed* was not answered by this answer. And the Q&A were unclear. They needed to be edited, to be helpful to others. *You've* done that now - OK. But as I said in another comment, that is tantamount to posing a different question, which I encouraged (and which would have been better, IMO). Otherwise *this question*, as posed, should have been closed as unclear. As for editing this question radically, as you've done, it would have been more helpful to all if the OP had edited it (or posed a separate question). The OP threw out a lousy question and never looked back.

Comment: @Drew Let's [continue this in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21699558#21699558).